# Report Generation in Git

Tags: git, report

Can anyone tell me, is there any option for generating report in git, Like unmerged branches in a repository, fetching branch name that's created during particular time period. 
If there is any separate tools for git report generation, kindly refer it.

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) examples you've applied to the problem. In addition, please post **relevant** error messages *verbatim*, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Answer (score 5):

This http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/ looks very interesting. Might help you.

Answer (score 0):

A report about what has changed on the various branches, which branches were merged, which were not, etc. probably depends too much on your actual workflow.

Junio C Hamano, the Git maintainer, uses such scripts to automatize the generation of its "[what's cooking](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/What-s-cooking-in-git-git-Jun-2012-01-Sun-3-td7560641.html)" emails.   These scripts are on the [todo branch](https://github.com/git/git/tree/todo) of the git repository, but I don't know if their use is documented somewhere...